# CVS command to list all available modules to checkout?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, cvs

I'm running CVS in a bash shell.

I'm just trying to see which modules are available for checkout.

I've been researching for a while and the only thing I've come up with is:

```
cvs checkout -c
```

which executes but shows nothing.  Now I know its possible that there may just be no modules to checkout, but thats more of a guess to me at this point, and settling for guesses rarely works out well.

UPDATE:

Im running version 1.11.23

apparently this version doesn't support `cvs ls`
Cheers.

Comment: cvs checkout -c shows you the contents of the CVSROOT/modules file but that file needs to be manually updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following hackery should work with 1.11.* client and server versions of cvs. I imagine it will work with others but those are the versions I have locally to test with.

```
mkdir -p dummy/CVS
cd dummy
echo . > CVS/Repository
touch CVS/Entries
cvs -d$CVSROOT -n co . | awk '{print $5}'
```

To apply this to arbitrarily nested directories in the cvs hierarchy the matching local directories must also exist. To find the directories available under `$CVSROOT/test_project/some_subdir` (for example) the following appears to work.

```
cd dummy
mkdir -p test_project/some_subdir
cvs -d$CVSROOT -n co test_project/some_subdir
```

Drop the awk if that doesn't show what you expect. The output might differ slightly from what I got.

If you are speaking the cvs wire protocol directly you can do a similar thing without the directory hackery I believe but I'd have to dig a bunch more to sort that out again. (I believe Zend/Eclipse does that when it detects an older cvs server version.)

Comment: I'll test this by Monday.  Sorry, on holiday til then.

Comment: cvs -d[CVSROOT] -n co . | awk '{print $5}' triggers the following error:

Comment: cvs checkout: CVSROOT must be an absolute pathname (not `[CVSROOT]')
cvs checkout: when using local access method.
cvs [checkout aborted]: Bad CVSROOT: `[CVSROOT]'.

Comment: That wasn't intended to be a literal string. That was a placeholder. I probably should have used `$CVSROOT` there or something. You need to use your normal -d string (or leave it off if your environment is set up to not need one (though I'm not sure that works for this case)).

Comment: ah!  That worked for the top level stuff!  To go one level deeper would I need to actually checkout one of those or just add the extra layer of path to my cvsroot?

Comment: I'm not sure but I would imagine you would just need to add the path to the cvsroot. Try it and let us know. =)

Comment: no that didn't work, but I'm thinking that if I go into that directory instead of running this from my base directory and do this process, it should probably work.  THanks.

Comment: The directory you are trying to look at needs to exist locally but that seems to be the only requirement. So `mkdir subpath` then `cvs ... co subpath` seems to work.

Comment: could you update your answer to reflect this with an example subpath named 'test_projects' if its not too much trouble?

Answer (score 3):

if your cvs version is new enough, you should be able to do a

```
cvs ls
```

if not, you can probably just go to the cvs server to examine the repo itself.

Comment: thanks for the help.  Apparently my version doesn't support that.  I updated the question with the cvs version as I forgot I could do a 'man cvs' to find out some things